# textbox + jquery how to asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-webforms

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var name = $("#name").text();
        $("#iname").val(name);
    });
</script>

<span id="name">Ivan</span>
<input type="text" name="iname" id="iname"/>
```

Это корректный код для input html. Как сделать аналогичный функционал для

```
<asp:TextBox ID="iname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам разобрался:

```
     var tname = $("#name").text();
     $("input[name*='txtname']").val(tname);


     <asp:TextBox ID="txtname" name="txtname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Надеюсь, что это кому-то пригодиться.

**UPD:** для textarea

```
        var tabout = $("#labout").text();
        $("textarea[name*='txtabout']").val(tabout);
```